# MongoDB indexes on multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

I've read the chapter on indexes in the MongoDB in action book and was wondering if anyone can expand upon what it talks about regarding indexes.

If I have an index that covers `a,b,c,d,e` and I query on `a,b,c` the index is used. What happens if I query on `a,c,e`? Is the index just used for the query on `a` or does it get used when querying on the other fields?

In this case does it make more sense to also have the index on `a,c,e`. I ask because I have a front end piece that links to these fields where users can create a free form query (`a,b,c,f` could be one). Do I need an index for all possible options that could come through?

Answer (score 5):

Compound indexes in MongoDB work via a prefix method.

So for an index of `a,b,c,d,e` `a` and `a,b` would be considered prefixes ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/indexes/#id5 ), as such querying on both `a,b,c` and `a,c,e` should yield an index usage; as to whether `a,c,e` uses the index performantly is another question entirely.

> I ask because I have a front end piece that links to these fields where users can create a free form query (a,b,c,f could be one). Do I need an index for all possible options that could come through?

Hmm if `a` is always first field defined then probably not (an `explain` would of course be better here on your dataset), otherwise you may require some combinations, yes.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about `explain`. I'll do some testing after adding the `a,b,c,d,e` index and see how it effects things.